# How to detect denial-of-service attack coming from my computer?

Tags: denial-of-service

Some websites I visit stop serving with a message

> There was a large number of requests coming from your IP-address, so it was
>   temporarily blocked by our system.

How can I check which requests are being sent from my computer?

Comment: You may have the IP from someone who have visited the website before or if you think you are infected, run a malware scan (e.g. with Malwarebyes) and monitor your network activity with tools like Wireshark

Answer (score 1):

You can use the netstat command on your machine to see all network connections from your computer to any external host.

```
netstat -an
```

Will show you the protocol, Local Address (your machine IP address), Foreign Address (the destination hosts/sites) and the State like (ESTABLISHED means there is an open/active connection to the destination address).

Example:

```
    C:\Users\myUser>netstat -an
    Active Connections

      Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
       TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
       TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
       TCP    127.0.0.1:2598         127.0.0.1:61196        ESTABLISHED
       TCP    172.27.12.86:49221     10.200.1.9:8883        ESTABLISHED
       TCP    172.27.12.86:50838     172.22.1.135:443       ESTABLISHED
```

Check if the amount of connections to a specific Foreign IP Address is high. There are other tools available out there but this is the simplest way to start to investigate.

This Works for both Windows and Linux machines.

References:

- https://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-verify-ddos-attack-with-netstat-command-on-linux-terminal
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack